# JQuery Page Refreshes

Tags: php, jquery

I working on a page with some JQuery and Kendo UI. This is my first JQuery project and I getting things along. However, my page refreshes for some reason. This is what I am trying to do: I have a text field where I can enter a search term and when I press a button, the query is sent to a php file and some json info will pop up. So far, I can get it to return something, but the page refreshs and all the data is gone.

code:

```
*<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Search</title>
    <link href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example">
    <form id="search">
        <label for="search">Search For:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="q">
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Find</button>
    </form>
    <div id="grid">
    </div>
</div>    
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    transport: {
                        read: "include/showsearch.php"
                    },
                    schema: {
                        data: "data"
                    }
                },
                columns: [{field: "id"},{field: "name"},{field: "season"}]
            });

            $("#submit").click(function(){
                var textVal = $("#txtSearch").val();
                var dynamicURL = "include/showsearch.php?show_name=" + textVal; 
                var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                alert("sdf123");
                grid.dataSource.transport.options.read.url = dynamicURL;
                grid.dataSource.read();
                alert("sdf");
            });         
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>*
```

NOTE:
I used the alert functions to stop and see how the page reacts. How do I get the page from refreshing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the default action for your submit button is still occurring; submitting the form.

It's probably best to catch the form submission event rather than the button click as hitting *Enter* in a text field may also submit the form.

You will also need to prevent the default event action.

Change this

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
```

to this

```
$('#search').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // and the rest of your code here
```

Comment: Or you could change the type of button from "submit" to just "button" :)